# Why are the variables not passing to the next view

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to pass 2 variables to a view using js and laravel,I got this code where I create the action URL for the form then submit it,but the information is not being passed,it just says that email is undefined in the confirmation view:

```js
var actionUrl = "{{ route('confirmation', ['email' => ':email', 'name' => ':name']) }}";
actionUrl = actionUrl.replace(':email', userEmail);
actionUrl = actionUrl.replace(':name', data.found.name);
var form = document.getElementById("specify-inform");
form.action = actionUrl;
form.submit();
```

I checked, `data.found.name` and `userEmail` are both with the right values but still not working

Comment: what is saying the email is undefined?

Comment: The action url redirects properly but without the variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright figurred it out,I could have just used the simple way of putting the inputs in the form then submit it without actually passing anything to the route in the action of the form,It looks like this:

```
    <form id = "specify-inform" action="{{route('confirmation')}}">
     ...
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" 
            placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name">
                <input id="specify-submit" type="submit" value="Next">
     ...
    </form>
     ...
    <script>
        $("#specify-submit").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //changing the hidden input which may take time
    $.ajax({ ... }).done(function(data) {
                    var form = document.getElementById("specify-inform");
                    $("#name").val(data.name);
                    //submiting the form with the changed name

                    form.submit();  
         });

   </script>
```

I hope this is helpful somehow for those which will need it